# append text to file including multiple quotes

Tags: bash, bash-scripting, bash-alias

I want to do this:

```
echo alias get_python_lib='python -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print get_python_lib();"' >> ~/.bash_aliases
```

The result in my `~/.bash_aliases` file is:

```
alias get_python_lib=python -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print get_python_lib();"
```

Unfortunately, the `echo` command stripped the first set of apostrophes (<kbd>'</kbd>), and the alias does not work.

I've tried all manner of apostrophe and quote swaps and used all the commands I could find as a substitute (`echo`, `type`, `cat`, `printf`), but nothing has worked.

How do I append a line of text to a file when the line of text requires all of its apostrophes and quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escaping the quotes works and adding wrapper quotes works:

```
echo alias get_python_lib=\'python -c "\"from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print get_python_lib();\""\' >> ~/.bash_aliases

$ cat .bash_aliases
alias get_python_lib='python -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print get_python_lib();"'
```

Answer (score 1):

Or stick double quotes around all the arguments to `echo` and escape the inner double quotes

```
echo "alias get_python_lib='python -c \"from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print get_python_lib();\"'" >> ~/.bash_aliases
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer; I used your solution just because it's a little simpler. Unfortunately I could only mark one as the "correct" answer, and the other was first.